# Issue with Full path .exe in PERL

Tags: windows, perl, command

I'm working on a script where I'm using the .exe full path and a command relate to that exe.

For Example:

Path  is `C:\Documents and Settings\xx\My Documents\utils.exe`

command is `dir |findstr -i xx |findstr -i tr`

My perl code is

```
$command='dir |findstr -i xx |findstr -i tr;
$path=C:\Documents and Settings\xx\My Documents\utils.exe
$result= `$path $command`;
```

I have tried many things like `system`, `push @cmd`,have gone through many blogs in google, but I'm really not able to find our any solution on this.

Could somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand out the code you get (assuming there should be a closing `'` on the `$command=` line).

```
$result= `C:\Documents and Settings\xx\My Documents\utils.exe dir |findstr -i xx |findstr -i tr`;
```

Note the space characters. They mean Perl is trying to run the program `C:\Documents` with arguments `and Settings\xx\My Documents\utils.exe dir` and pipe that into `findstr`.

Quoting the executable name should help with making the exe run:

```
$result= `"$path" $command`;
```

Another possibility is to change the working directory to `C:\Documents and Settings\xx\My Documents` and then run the program with:

```
$result= `utils.exe $command`;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much :)   This solution is working fine $result= `"$path" $command`;